# regex match all but excluding quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, ip

I am currently trying to match all ip addresses excluding double quotes from this following string:

```
"1.2.3.4/1.0", "1.2.3.4/a", "10.0.2.3/1"
```

And below is my regex pattern:

```
(?<=")\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/.*(?=")
```

However the result only removes the first and last double quotes, but still keeps other double quotes in the middle:

```
1.2.3.4/1.0", "1.2.3.4/a", "10.0.2.3/1
```

The result that I want is this:

```
1.2.3.4/1.0, 1.2.3.4/a, 10.0.2.3/1
```

How do I exclude double quotes when matching all these ip addresses?

P.S. I know this is not the proper ip Address matching, but I did this for testing purpose, what I am concerned with is excluding the double quotes when matching all occurrences of ip addresses.

Additionally I have to do a strip on the comma after the regex matching. It would be great if you could help me figure out how to get each ip address from one regex matching.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just a simple `(?<=")[^"]+(?=")` in a global find. Add the comma's after each match. Otherwise you don't look like you're validating ip addresses,   which is another thing entirely.

Comment: Yep, that would work for the string I attached above, which is actually only a part of the string I was working with. The purpose of this was not to validate but to get all ip addresses including the ones with malformed subnet masks, so that I can filter them later on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use lookarounds, you can use this regex:

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/[^"]+)?
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI4qF0/1)

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! By the way, I tried to understand how this works from the link you gave me, but I am still confused. Would you mind giving me an explantation on your regex? Specifally for the last part, (?:/[^"]+)?, I don't get why you have a + and ? in the end.

Comment: I used `?` to make part after `/` optional since IP address can be just `11.22.33.44` I used `(?:...)` for non capturing group and `[^"]+` will match anything before a double quote.